# can we remove AngularJS after loading it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-management

In our application, we will need to load another single page application (AngualarJS 1.5 app) temporary into DOM and them remove it.

But notice that destroy the DOM will not remove the script it brought together. e.g AngularJS library.

Is there a way to free AngularJS from memory as well?

a workaround would load the app into an iframe, but would like to know if there is another way than make the change to use iframe.

Comment: You can try getting all scripts and manually checking it. You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('script')`

Comment: maybe someone will answer differently but believe the only way to cleanly do this is with an iframe really.  When angular loads it "compiles" the html looking for directives and adding event listeners to elements which may not be cleaned up even after removing things from the DOM (thinking of cases where someone might attach a listener to the document or body) https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler